# How to delete a server endpoint for a deleted windows server on azure

Tags: azure

I created a windows server and registered it with azure storage sync service. After deleting the resource group it belonged to I expected the service to be deleted too but it says I need to delete the  server endpoint first, then the service.

So when I try to do this it fails with the error:

```
Server endpoint 'FileServerLocal'
Code: MgmtServerJobExpired
Details: The operation 
'Delete server endpoint' failed with the following error: 
The server did not pick up the new configuration. 
Check if the server is turned off, or is having service connectivity issues. 
If the server has been decommissioned, unregister the server.
```

The problem here is that the process of deleting the resource group had deleted the server in question so I can't decommission it as directed. I need help on how to delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I am new to azure so didn't see or know about the "deregistration" option in the Storage Sync Service. So I went to the "Registered servers" under "sync" menu and was able to "unregister" the server and finally delete the "server endpoint"